# Cant read jsonarray with json object, NPE

Tags: java, json, parsing, nullpointerexception

I am new with JSON format and Java. If I am missing a point pls inform me.

This is my parser code. path is true. I can read the blabla part if I wrote it. But examples.size always null. So I could not read the rest of file.
I use json simple 1.1.1

```
   `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(path);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray examples= (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("example");
        System.out.println("Example SIZE:" + examples.size());`
```

I can't share my exact json file but this is similar format to my JSON:

```
{
  "examples":{
    "blabla":"blabla",
    "example":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "firstName":"Leonardo",
        "lastName":"DiCaprio",
        "photo":"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-zvS_6Q1IzR8/T5l6qvnRmcI/AAAAAAAABcc/HXO7HDEJKo0/s200/Leonardo+Dicaprio7.jpg",
        "movieandpoint":[
          {
            "movie":"Inception",
            "point":"9.1"
          },
          {
            "movie":"Catch me if you can",
            "point":"8"
          }
        ],
        "decision":{
          "user":"admin",
          "#text":"ok"
        },
        "movieandpoint#1":[
          {
            "movie":"another one",
            "point":"7"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "firstName":"Johnny",
        "lastName":"Depp",
        "photo":"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_xR71w9-qx9E/SrAz--pu0MI/AAAAAAAAC38/2ZP28rVEFKc/s200/johnny-depp-pirates.jpg",
        "movieandpoint":[
          {
            "movie":"Sweeny Tod",
            "point":"9"
          },
          {
            "movie":"Yoga Hosers",
            "point":"5"
          }
        ],
        "decision":{
          "user":"admin",
          "#text":"ok"
        },
        "movieandpoint#1":[
          {
            "movie":"another",
            "point":"9"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your test json input to your question and note which library you are using. In your example code there is a typo in the key (`exapmle`).

Comment: And there seems to be a comma missing after the blabla value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read from parent to child. something like below will work. First you have to read the "examples" jsonobject and then the child "exapmle". By the way I could not run this with your json file, like other users have mentioned in comment, the json file is not structurally correct.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = parser.parse(aa);
    org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) obj;
    org.json.simple.JSONObject object1 = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) jsonObject.get("examples");
   JSONArray examples = (JSONArray) object1.get("example");
    System.out.println("Example SIZE:" + examples.size());
```

Comment: yes, im sorry i fixed the json file. but this is not work for me thy anyway

Comment: @anchors I updated as per the latest json. try now, you changed the array name to "example" in new json, the code needed to be updated according to that. Also parser.parse(aa), aa is string variable containing the json, update this according to your code. it could be a string or read from a file

Comment: oh, i see that you call object1.get("example"), I miss that . I try to call it jsonObject.get also. Thank you so much it worked !